# Does dup2 do more than copy a file descriptor?

Tags: c, operating-system, dup2

First, I open a file, then I use `dup2` to copy the file descriptor. Why, when the first file descriptor is closed, can I still read the file through the other one?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd,fd2=7;   /*7 can be any number < the max file desc*/
    char buf[101];

    if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY))<0)      /*open a file*/
        perror("open error");
    dup2(fd,fd2);                             /*copy*/
    close(fd);

    if(read(fd2,buf,100)<0)
        perror("read error");
    printf("%s\n",buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, the actual "open file description" data is reference-counted, so that all that happens when you duplicate a file descriptor is that the count for the data it references is incremented. When you call `close()`, the count is decremented.

Thus, your closing of the first descriptor doesn't actually render the second one invalid.

Comment: thank you. you are right. i find it [close-file-descriptor](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/what-happens-when-i-close-a-file-descriptor).